# Getting a remainder without the modulo (%) operator in Javascript, accounting for -/+ sign

Tags: javascript, modulo

For a homework assignment, I need to return the remainder after dividing num1 by num2 WITHOUT using the built-in modulo (%) operator.  I'm able to get most tests to pass with the following code, but I'm stuck on how to account for -/+ signs of the given numbers.  I need to carry over whichever sign is on num1, and also return a positive number if the num2 is negative - it's blowing my mind how to do this... :)  Any clarity would be greatly appreciated!  I'm not exactly looking for the straight up answer here, more that I seem to be missing something obvious...  Maybe I need a new approach?

```
    function modulo(num1, num2) {
      if (num1 === 0) {
        return 0;
      }
      if (num2 === 0 || isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
        return NaN;
      }
      if (num1 < num2) {
        return num1;
      }
      if (num1 > 0 && num2 > 0) {
        var counter = num1;
      while (counter >= Math.abs(num2)) {
        counter = counter - num2;
      }
      return counter;
      }
    }
    var output = modulo(25, 4);
    console.log(output); // 1
```

Comment: What is the expected output for e.g. `modulo(-25, 4)` and `modulo(25, -4)`?

Comment: Btw, `%` is the *remainder* operator in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be overthinking this. You basically stated the solution in your question:

> I need to carry over whichever sign is on num1, and also return a positive number if the num2 is negative

The second part isn't accurate, but I suspect you just misspoke. A positive number should be returned when `num2` is negative *unless* `num1` is negative.

At any rate, the important takeaway is that if `num1` is negative the result will be negative, and otherwise the result will be positive. The sign of `num2` is discarded.

Starting the code you've written (which others will be quick to point out isn't the simplest solution), the fix is to compute the remainder using both numbers' absolute values, and then apply `num1`'s original sign to the result.

```js
function modulo(num1, num2) {
  var sign = num1 < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  var dividend = Math.abs(num1);
  var divisor = Math.abs(num2);

  if (dividend === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (dividend === 0 || isNaN(dividend) || isNaN(divisor)) {
    return NaN;
  }
  if (dividend < divisor) {
    return sign * dividend;
  }
  
  var counter = dividend;
  while (counter >= divisor) {
    counter = counter - divisor;
  }
  return sign * counter;
}

console.log( 25 %  4, modulo( 25,  4));
console.log(-25 %  4, modulo(-25,  4));
console.log( 25 % -4, modulo( 25, -4));
console.log(-25 % -4, modulo(-25, -4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: @quikst3r I was surprised OP accepted this answer as well, since it was intended as a companion to Pabs123's answer (which I upvoted) to show OP how they might modify their existing code. As the work of a beginner I personally wouldn't dismiss it as "a terrible solution," but that's just me. Thanks for your feedback anyway.

Answer (score 10):

If you think about the mathematical process to calculate modulus you might be able see how you can do this without having to resort to a bunch of case statements. Instead think of it this way, you're just calculating a remainder:

Given 2 numbers a and b, you can compute `mod(a,b)` by doing the following:

```
q = a / b;  //finding quotient (integer part only)
p = q * b;  //finding product
remainder = a - p;  //finding modulus
```

Using this idea, you should be able to transfer it to JS. You said you're not looking for the straight up answer so that's all I'll say!

**Edit:** here is the code, like I said in the comments it's exactly the pseudocode I posted above:

```
function modulo(a,b){
  q = parseInt(a / b);  //finding quotient (integer part only)
  p = q * b;  //finding product
  return a - p;  //finding modulus
}
```

This will return the exact same values as using %

Comment: not if you only grab the integer part from `q = a/b` edit: looks like @jordan deleted his comment, but I was answering "your math will always give a remainder of zero"

Comment: My mistake. This won't give the same result as JavaScript's `%` operator, but it's unclear how the homework assignment defines "modulo."

Comment: no problem @Jordan. It will actually give you the exact same result as the `%` operator, at least from my testing. I have the code written out but I don't want to give it away if OP doesn't want full solution

Comment: Ugh. My mistake again. I forgot that `Math.floor` rounds toward -Infinity, not 0.

Comment: Here's what I have now - I am now open to more efficient ways of doing this, now that I got my logic to work out (including absolute value when accounting for the -/+ sign).  Thoughts?

Comment: function modulo(num1, num2) {
          if (num1 === 0) {
              return 0;
            }
            if (num2 === 0 || isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
              return NaN;
            }
            var divisor = Math.abs(num2);
            var remainder = Math.abs(num1);
            while (remainder >= divisor) {
               remainder -= divisor;
             }
            if (Math.sign(num1) === -1) {
              return -Math.abs(remainder);
            }
            return remainder;
        }

Comment: @R.Noble it doesn't look like you really read my post at all, you just reposted the code from your question... you can do the whole thing with the pseudocode I posted above, the only thing missing is a parse to int on the first line

Comment: Um, it's different...  And your post is basically the math for how modulo works, I used that to start the logic for this question.  I was trying to find clarity on how the +/- works with the math...  We haven't learned about parse to int, I'll look it up...

Comment: you can write the solution to what you're asking using exactly the pseudocode I posted. it is a 5 line solution

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic formula:
`dividend = divisor * quotient + remainder`
From this equation you can calculate the remainder.

Comment: maybe you could format the formula with backticks ` for better readability